SQL aggregate whether table contains a category or type of record
Can anyone think of a better way to structure a SQL query for this problem?
I want to group by account_id and determine whether a type of row exists in the table and just aggregate that to a simple true/false as to whether that type of row exists for that account_id
TABLE user_account_values
COLUMNS:
user_id,
account_id,
svc_id,
card_id,
name,
status

Account_id is not unique in the table
e.g. result is something like below, where category is determined by a defined list of possible values



AccountID
Category1Exists
Category2Exists




123
true
false


124
false
true


125
false
false



My current solution is to create a type of bitmap based on whether the row matches the category then aggregate that with MAX() to select 1 as true if the category exists for the account_id
SELECT 
    account_id, 
    MAX(first) AS firstExists, 
    MAX(final) AS finalExists
FROM
    (SELECT 
         account_id,
         CASE 
             WHEN name IN ('something1_first', 'something2_first')
                 THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
         END AS first,
         CASE 
             WHEN name IN ('something1_final', 'something2_final') 
                 THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
         END AS final
     FROM  
         user_account_values 
     WHERE 
         user_id = :user  
         AND account_id IS NOT NULL
         AND status = 'A')
GROUP BY 
    account_id

Is there a simpler way to achieve this?
I also thought maybe you could have a select account_id where name in (*) for each category and then join them all together on account_id but it seems like it would be worse performance and I may have upwards of 4/5 categories I need to check in the final query.

Combine a conditional within aggregation.
SELECT account_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN (name IN ('something1_first','something2_first')) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) firstexists,
       MAX(CASE WHEN (name IN ('something1_final','something2_final')) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) finalexists
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY account_id

This works because Y collates higher than N so if there's a single Y coming from that case function the overall result will be Y. There are of course numerous variations on this theme, but this shows the concept.
If you literally want the string 'true' and 'false' (you can't have real Booleans, at least not as of 19c) you could substitute those for Y and N because true will evaluate higher than false alphabetically. But that's not good programming because not as self-evident. If you definitely wanted the strings and didn't want to rely on the accidental ordering between these two strings, then simply translate Y/N (or 0/1 or whatever properly orders) to whatever string you prefer:
SELECT account_id,
       DECODE(MAX(CASE WHEN (name IN ('something1_first','something2_first')) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END),'Y','true','false') firstexists,
       DECODE(MAX(CASE WHEN (name IN ('something1_final','something2_final')) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END),'Y','true','false') finalexists
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY account_id


This is one of the things I like about MySQL. Boolean expressions evaluate as 1 or 0, so you can use them directly in MAX(), ORDER BY, etc. without having to wrap in CASE.

@Barmar, Even with a real boolean (which I think I've heard is now available in 23ai) you'd still have to use case/decode and aggregation. Having a real boolean only substitutes for using Y/N or 0/1, which isn't that much of a benefit.

Right, that's why it's nice that they become numbers, so you can compare them.

Nice, I didn't realize I could directly put the case statement into the aggregation but I guess that makes sense. The result type doesn't really matter to me as I can always do some handling in my dataLayer which calls this to convert 0, 1 or Y, N to true/false in my result set transformation.
